# How to replace special charcters like "Ã¶" from a string and give them the right characters "Ö"?

Tags: java, android, google-geocoder

Hey I use the reverse Google Geocoder and when the cityname is for example "Königsaich" then the geocoder names it "KÃ¶nigsaich" . How do I filter the "Ã¶" character and replace it with the right character "ö" ?

**EDIT:**

My code:

```
public JSONObject getJSONCity(double lat, double lon){

         HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=false");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                response = client.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonObject;
    }


    public String getCityname(double lat, double lon){

        JSONObject ret = getJSONCity(lat,lon); 
         JSONArray jsonArray;

         JSONObject location;
         String location_string;

         try {
             jsonArray = ret.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");
             cityname = jsonArray.getJSONObject(2).getString("long_name");

             //Get JSON Array called "results" and then get the 0th complete object as JSON        
             location = ret.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0); 
             // Get the value of the attribute whose name is "formatted_string"
             location_string = location.getString("formatted_address");

             System.out.println(" results: " + location_string);

             System.out.println(" My City: " + cityname);
         } catch (JSONException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }
         return cityname;
    }
```

Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: If you've got the wrong data in the string, you need to take a step back and fix it earlier in the process - typically where you've got a "bytes to text" conversion. Please show us how you're using the Geocoder API.

Comment: i think u got error while russian name is coming M i correct ?

Comment: I think yoiu can apply regular expression concept there..

Comment: look my edit. I gave u my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String actualstring ="what ever your string which you want to replace here get ";
         if(actualstring.contains("here your string which u want to chk"));
                { 
                   // it chk weather it contain that string which u want to replace 
           actualstring.replace("target", "replacement");
                 }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there are many thousands of characters that will be read incorrectly, if you read bytes from the `HttpEntity` and treat them as characters.  Do you propose including this piece of code thousands and thousands of time?  This is completely the wrong way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: 
String rightName = responseName.replace("Ã¶", "ö");

For more detail:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm

Comment: and what about all the other characters that will be read incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str = str.replace(' ','_');
```

public String replace (CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) 
Added in API level 1
Copies this string replacing occurrences of the specified target sequence with another sequence. The string is processed from the beginning to the end.

Parameters
target  the sequence to replace. 
replacement  the replacement sequence.

Returns
the resulting string.
Throws
NullPointerException  if target or replacement is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are reading bytes from your `HttpEntity`, and assuming that each byte will be a single character.  Depending on your encoding, that may work for ASCII characters, but is likely to fail for many other characters.

To do this correctly, instead of setting up sophisticated search/replace combinations, you want to use a library such as Apache's HTTP Utils library.  It contains a class `EntityUtils` which has some methods for reading a string from an `HttpEntity`.

The Javadoc for it is at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html